# Reduce Logging Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I have a Rails 5 app that listens for events from a third party service. This third party service consistently streams events which makes several requests to my app and as a result, there is a lot of request logs that are most times irrelevant. I want to be able to completely eliminate request logs and only log for only relevant events that can be processed, but for irrelevant events, there is no point logging.

So I have an EventsController with a create action. This action

```
class EventsController
  before_action :ensure_valid_event, only: :create

  def create
    ...
    process_event
    ...
  end

  private

  def ensure_valid_event
    unless Event.exists?(event_name: params[:event])
      head :ok
    end
  end

end
```

What's the best way to go about this without using a gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this and I think we'll help your case is to:

1. Disable logging completely from the config/environments file
2. Re-enable logging for the create action for only valid events

To disable logging, edit the right environment config file. E.g: `config/environments/production.rb` and replace the config.logger line with this:

```
config.logger = Logger.new("/dev/null")
```

Now in your events_controller, do:

```
class EventsController

  before_action :enable_logging, only: :create
  after_action :disable_logging, only: :create

  private

  def enable_logging
    if valid_event?
      Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    end
  end

  def disable_logging
    Rails.logger = Logger.new("/dev/null")
  end

  def valid_event?
    Event.exists?(name: params[:event])
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this will work. Do we need to disable logging afterwards? I think once logging is enabled for one request, it will become enabled for subsequent requests

Comment: Hmm.. yea, I guess so, considering `Rails.logger` is a singleton. You can have a disable_logging callback in an `after_action` :only: :create, that sets `Rails.logger` back to `/dev/null`. I'll update my answer

Comment: This way there'll be no `Started ...` log entries, because they are emitted by rails before controller is created

Comment: yea, from the post you will see that @erika is not interested in any of the request logs. He just wants application-specific logs I guess for debugging

Comment: I mean that even for relevant events logs will be incomplete (no usual rails `Started GET ... Parameters...`), only these logged from controller itself - debugging will be harder

Answer (score 0):

You can make a middleware, that'll filter requests:

```
class FilterEventsMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['PATH_INFO'] =~ %r{\A/your/events/endpoint_path}
      # event name extraction may be different depending on how they are passed
      request = ActionDispatch::Request.new env
      event_name = request.params[:event]

      return [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ['']] unless Event.exists?(name: event_name)
    end
    @call.call(env)
  end
end

config.middleware.insert_before Rails::Rack::Logger, FilterEventsMiddleware
```

this way there's no reason to disable logging application-wide, irrelevant events will not hit the controller at all